# Why does prepared statement cause wrong number of parameters in bind?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting the

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters
```

warning

From the following statement:

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $str_addr_no, $str_addr);`

I've looked around for `where ... like` examples, and cannot see what is wrong with my syntax.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","fred","password","h2o_amr");

$str_addr_no = $_REQUEST['meter_street_number'];
$str_addr    = $_REQUEST['meter_street_address'];

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "select w.* from water w where w.mtr_addr_no like '?%' and w.mtr_addr_str like '?%' "))

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $str_addr_no, $str_addr);
```

Is there a way to get PHP to reveal or to examine the prepared statement to see how many parameters were actually prepared?

Answer (score 4):

You quoted your placeholders: `'?%'`, which turns them into strings, not placeholders. A placeholder must be a BARE `?` character:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo = ? // OK
SELECT ... WHERE Foo = '?' // no parameters here, just a string
```

For a wildcarded `LIKE` query, you have to resort to hacks:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)
```

Comment: Instead of that hack you can concatenate the `%` in the PHP code.